# Plotting Nominal Variables in R using subsets

Tags: r

I am trying to plot only certain nominal variables using subsets. I can plot states US, Japan, China, but I only want to plot Japan.

```
    plot(da$Q1[da$Q1 = 'Japan'])

    Error: unexpected '=' in "plot(da$Q1[da$Q1 ="
    > plot(da$Q1[Q1 = 'Japan'])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can try using "==" instead of "=".

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(da$Q1[da$Q1 == 'Japan'])
```

Thanks to Pawel Kolodziej